# Asterisk AGI file returns ImportError

Tags: python, centos, asterisk, agi

I have inherited a cluster of CentOS Asterisk servers, one of which runs a check that I've been tasked with replicating on the other servers.

Part of this check involves an AGI that runs without problem on the first server - but on the other servers, spits out `ImportError: No module named asterisk.agi`

The line in the AGI that seems to cause the issue is `from asterisk.agi import *`

The only differences I can see between the working server and the non-working is the Python version. Typing `python` in the working server returns

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan  9 2013, 06:49:54)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
```

..however, in the non-working servers returns

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
```

I've googled and can't find where I'm going wrong. I'm wary of breaking other dependencies, as there are a number of AGI scripts running on these servers.

Does anyone have any pointers or advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

I needed to install [Pyst](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyst/0.6.50) which included the relevant libraries (asterisk.agi, etc).

Simples! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing python modules. Install them with distribution package manager (if available) or use `pip install <module name>`. You have to check which module is used by your script. Check lib directories with python modules.

https://docs.python.org/2.7/installing/

Comment: Thanks - I believe this would work in the majority of cases, but Python 2.6.6 doesn't come with Pip, and make_install was a headache. I solved this by installing Pyst (see my answer below). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade your Python version from Python 2.6.6 to Python 2.4.3.

Comment: I don't think this would have helped - the issue was the missing modules, not the Python version. Thanks for the help though :)